# How can I change a label text without interfering with an input radio inside the label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label, radio-group

In my html template  I've got a label with an input radio inside:

```
<label id="myid" class="inline">
    <input type="radio" value ="11"> 
    my text
</label>
```

I need to change the text of the label with jquery. I tried this:

```
$('#myid').html('my new text');
```

or

```
$('#myid').text('my new text');
```

but when I do that I lose my input radio. How can I preserve the input radio inside the label and modify label's text?

Comment: `$('#myid input').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue = 'my new text';`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#myid').contents().last().replaceWith('my new text');
```

Answer (score 6):

Put your text in a `span` and try this:

```
<label id="myid" class="inline">
    <input type="radio" value ="11">
    <span>my text</span>
</label>
```

```
$('#myid').find("span").text('my new text');
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rn79L04p/1/)**